# Page header alternatively author name and short title

Tags: header-footer

I'm using the `a4paper` environment for a scientific article and I want to make headers that display alternatively author names and short title each page, while getting rid of all page numberings. We did get rid of page numbers by using `\pagestyle{empty}` but we can't do the header thing. How should we make a header that displays name and title alternatively each page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular, it's unclear what an `a4paper` "environment" is -- it might be a class option of your (unkown) document class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package; if the `twoside` class option is allowed, you can say something like this (I placed the information centered in the header, but you can place it flushed to one of the margins):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\shorttitle{The Short Title}
\newcommand\authors{Author A, Author B and AuthorC}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE]{\small\scshape\shorttitle}
\fancyhead[CO]{\small\scshape\authors}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

If `twoside` is not allowed, you can say something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\shorttitle{The Short Title}
\newcommand\authors{Author A, Author B and AuthorC}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\ifodd\value{page}
  \small\scshape\authors
\else
  \small\scshape\shorttitle
\fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

An image of the header of two consecutive pages:

[image]

Comment: But how can I set the page numbering on the left if the authors names are displayed in the header and on the right if the title of the paper is displayed ?!.