# Print a short title in the header

Tags: titles, fancyhdr, automation, titling

I'm creating a style file to use as a template for submissions to a specific journal. That journal requires a short title in the header. I could easily hard-code such a short title in the style file itself, following the answer to [Page header alternatively author name and short title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74034/page-header-alternatively-author-name-and-short-title), but that's clearly not a good solution in this case, as I would need to change the template `.sty` file for every document I write. Any suggestions how I can do this? Dummy lines with `\shorttitle` are commented out in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.sty}
%% My package starts here
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thetitle\ \thepage} % Instead of this
%   \fancyhead[R]{\theshorttitle\ \thepage} % do something like this
\endinput
%% And ends here
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\title{This is my long title}
%\shorttitle{This is my short title} % This short title should not be printed here - only in the header
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about using a key-value interface for your command/style file?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Something like `\usepackage[shorttitle={Yet another sophisticated Title]{mystyle}` as class/style option, e.g. created with `xkeyval` package?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Still way over my head :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you can do what you want by defining a command in the .sty such as

```
\newcommand\@shorttitle{}
% define \theshorttitle to what is given
\newcommand\shorttitle[1]{\renewcommand\@shorttitle{#1}}
```

You can then use `\@shorttitle` in the .sty file in place of where you need it (e.g. defining the header; just use `\@shorttitle` instead of `\theshorttitle`). You can set the short title from your main document as you suggest, with

```
\shorttitle{This is my short title}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Usually, commands beginning with `\the...` indicate that they are purposed counter output formatting, not for titles itself. And the usage of `\def` is not necessary here where the safer `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` would suffice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If phfaist's suggestion is essentially correct, though, please edit the answer to reflect your objections.

Comment: @Sverre: They are essentially correct, I wanted to indicate rather a matter of style, not more or less.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I understood that. Yet, please edit his answer so that it ends up being a suggestion I (and others who read this) can plug into a preamble or ``.sty`` file.

Comment: @Sverre: I could (possible) edit his answer, but this is not my task.

Comment: I just used `\theshorttitle` because Sverre referenced that particular command in his example. I agree, something like `\@shorttitle` is more appropriate; I've edited my answer.

Comment: I think it also would be better to avoid using ``\def``, but I don't know exactly what needs changing when using ``\(re)newcommand`` instead. Anyone?

Comment: There you go. I'm not sure which advantages `\newcommand` gives here over `\def` (e.g. in LaTeX itself the `\title{}` command is implemented with `\def`, see `<texlive-dir>/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx`), but I'm happy to hear if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

In the `amsart` class, the command `\title` has an optional parameter which does exactly that:

```
\title[This is my short title]{This is my long title}
```

Maybe copy their implementation?