# Print a macro I created in a package

Tags: macros, packages

Based on the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173060/9077) I received to [Print a short title in the header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173055/print-a-short-title-in-the-header), I've created the macro `\handoutheader` in a `.sty` file I use as the template for my conference presentations.

```
\newcommand\@confname{} % create macro for name of conference
\newcommand\confname[1]{\renewcommand\@confname{#1}}
\newcommand\@confplace{} % create macro for place of conference
\newcommand\confplace[1]{\renewcommand\@confplace{#1}}
\newcommand\@confdate{} % create macro for date of conference
\newcommand\confdate[1]{\renewcommand\@confdate{#1}}
\newcommand{\handoutheader}{%
    My name \hfill \@confname\\
    My affiliation \hfill \@confplace\\
    My e-mail address \hfill \@confdate\\} % make handout header
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\handoutheader}
```

The logic is that I specify in the preamble of the `.tex` file for the handout what the name, place, and date of the conference is, and then the template creates a header on the handout with that information.

Now, I'd like to print the date of my presentation in the handout text. How do I do that? I've tried `\confdate` and `\@confdate`, but neither works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.sty}
%% My package starts here
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newcommand\@confname{} % create macro for name of conference
\newcommand\confname[1]{\renewcommand\@confname{#1}}
\newcommand\@confplace{} % create macro for place of conference
\newcommand\confplace[1]{\renewcommand\@confplace{#1}}
\newcommand\@confdate{} % create macro for date of conference
\newcommand\confdate[1]{\renewcommand\@confdate{#1}}
\newcommand{\handoutheader}{%
    My name \hfill \@confname\\
    My affiliation \hfill \@confplace\\
    My e-mail address \hfill \@confdate\\} % make handout header
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\handoutheader}
\endinput
%% And ends here
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mystyle}
\confname{Name of conference}
\confplace{Place of conference}
\confdate{Date of conference}

\begin{document}
\vspace{2ex}\\
After hearing my talk, you will remember the date \confdate\ for the rest of your life.\\
After hearing my talk, you will remember the date \@confdate\ for the rest of your life.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `\confdate` takes an argument. Therefore, when you use

```
...remember the date \confdate\ for the rest of your life.
```

the `\`  (control space) is grabbed as the argument and placed inside `\@confdate`. That's why your output resembles

> ...remember the date for the rest of your life.

On the other hand, when you use

```
...remember the date \@confdate\ for the rest of your life.
```

the interpretation is to call [`\@`, which inserts a very large `\spacefactor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22561/5764) - and what remains is `confdate` . As such, the output is

> ...remember the date confdate for the rest of your life.

Ideally you should create yourself a macro that shows the "privilege content". In the case below, I've created `\printdate` which sets `\@confdate` - the macro the holds the date.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.sty}
%% My package starts here
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newcommand\@confname{} % create macro for name of conference
\newcommand\confname[1]{\renewcommand\@confname{#1}}
\newcommand\@confplace{} % create macro for place of conference
\newcommand\confplace[1]{\renewcommand\@confplace{#1}}
\newcommand\@confdate{} % create macro for date of conference
\newcommand\confdate[1]{\renewcommand\@confdate{#1}}
\newcommand{\printdate}{\@confdate}
\newcommand{\handoutheader}{%
    My name \hfill \@confname\\
    My affiliation \hfill \@confplace\\
    My date \hfill \@confdate\\} % make handout header
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\handoutheader}
\endinput
%% And ends here
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mystyle}
\confname{Name of conference}
\confplace{Place of conference}
\confdate{Date of conference}

\begin{document}

\bigskip

After hearing my talk, you will remember the date \printdate{} for the rest of your life.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The two main problems were:

1. To use the `@` in macro mames you need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. See the references below.
2. The definition

   ```
    \newcommand\confdate[1]{\renewcommand\@confdate{#1}}
   ```

   means that calling `\confdate` sets the value of `\@confdate` to the first parmamater. In your code the first line (which is commented out in the MWE below) was resetting the value of `\@confdate` to be blank, which was then printed out in the subsequent call to `\@confdate`. Comenting out that call fixes the problem.

[image]

### Notes:

- I'd recommend you not use `\\` at the end of a new line. Just leave a blank line to indicate a new paragraph break.
- If you don't want to use `\makeatletter` just don't use a macro name that has an `@` in it, or define a macro such as `\ShowConfDate` shown in the MWE.

### References

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) and
- [\makeatletter explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106174/makeatletter-explained)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.sty}
%% My package starts here
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newcommand\@confname{} % create macro for name of conference
\newcommand\confname[1]{\renewcommand\@confname{#1}}

\newcommand\@confplace{} % create macro for place of conference
\newcommand\confplace[1]{\renewcommand\@confplace{#1}}
\newcommand\@confdate{} % create macro for date of conference
\newcommand\confdate[1]{\renewcommand\@confdate{#1}}
\newcommand\ShowConfDate{\@confdate}%

\newcommand{\handoutheader}{%
    My name \hfill \@confname\\
    My affiliation \hfill \@confplace\\
    My e-mail address \hfill \@confdate\\} % make handout header
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\handoutheader}
\endinput
%% And ends here
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mystyle}
\confname{Name of conference}
\confplace{Place of conference}
\confdate{Date of conference}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
%After hearing my talk, you will remember the date \confdate\ for the rest of your life.
After hearing my talk, you will remember the date \@confdate\ for the rest of your life.
\makeatother

\medskip
If you don't want to be using \verb|\makeatletter| you can use \verb|\ShowConfDate| as in:
``The date is \ShowConfDate."
\end{document}
```

Comment: That clearly works, but is there another way that doesn't require me to include macros like ``\makeatletter`` in the document text? I generally prefer to keep those in preambles and package files. EDIT: Never mind, I'm happy with ``\makeatletter\@confdate\makeatletter``.

Comment: @Sverre: Have updated solution to show that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to allocate new name for printing version of the macro `\confname`, you can define more intelligent version of such macro: if the equal sign immediately follows then the value is stored else the value is used. Example:

```
The test: \confname\         % value is used, empty value is printed as default.
\confname={Name}             % the value "Name" is stored.
The second test: \confname\  % the value "Name" is printed.
```

The implementation looks like:

```
\def\confname{\futurelet\next\confnameA}
\def\confnameA{\ifx\next=\expandafter\confnameB \else \confnameC\fi}
\def\confnameB=#1{\def\confnameC{#1}}
\def\confnameC{}
```

But we are lazy to write this code three times (for `\confname`, `\confplace`, `\confdate`). So, we can create a more intelligent macro:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\setmacro#1{%
   \sdef{#1}{\expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next\csname#1.A\endcsname}%
   \sdef{#1.A}{\ifx\next=\csname#1.B\expandafter\endcsname \else \csname#1.C\endcsname\fi}%
   \sdef{#1.B}=##1{\sdef{#1.C}{##1}}%
}
\setmacro{confname} \setmacro{confplace} \setmacro{confdate}
```

You can insert this code to your `.sty` file instead `\newcommand\@confname...\newcommand\confdate` and you can replace the `\@confname` etc. by `\confname` etc. in the body of your macro `\handoutheader`. And, of course, the usage is slightly different:

```
\confname={Name of conference}
\confplace={Place of conference}
\confdate={Date of conference}
```

Comment: Laziness is a virtue `:-)`

Comment: I'm sure this is indeed more intelligent, which is probably why I don't understand much of the code ... ``:P``