# Use monospaced numbers in gb4e's example number, but proportional elsewhere

Tags: fontspec, oldstylenums, gb4e, liningnums

I'm using proportional numbers in my document. But in [`gb4e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e)'s example numbers, I would like to have monospaced numbers, so that the width of the example parenthesis remains the same throughout my document.

In the MWE below, I would in other words like to have the example numbers `(1)` and `(2)` monospaced, so that their width is the same, but the number sequences `021345` should use proportional numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{gb4e}
    \exewidth{(9)} % change the default (999) to one digit (9)
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 012345
\ex 012345
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the `pnum` feature when the label is being created:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@exe}
  {(\thexnumi)}
  {(\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-pnum}\thexnumi)}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\setmainfont[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}

\exewidth{(9)} % change the default (999) to one digit (9)

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 012345
\ex 012345
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you want to change the with parameter to `(9)` because that will left align the numbers rather than right align them (noticeable when the numbers have more than one digit).

Comment: @AlanMunn That's the OP's choice.

Comment: In my actual document, this creates an error message ``Command \@ already defined`` because I have defined commands such as ``\@confname`` elsewhere (see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205018/print-a-macro-i-created-in-a-package)). Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: @Sverre Commands like `\@confname` should be defined between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: @AlanMunn I use ``\exewidth{(9)}`` when my document has $<10$ ``\ex`` commands and ``\exewidth{(99)}`` when it has $<100 >9$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at `gb4e` and it looks so complicated that this solution might cause problems in a more realistic document, but it works for your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{gb4e}
    \exewidth{(9)} % change the default (999) to one digit (9)
% ----------------------------  
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\makebox[.6em][c]{\@xsi{xnumi}}}
\makeatother
% ----------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 012345
\ex 012345
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to put the example numbers into a fixed width box.

[image]

Comment: I'd be wary of redefining `\thexnumi` in that way, because it's used also for cross-references.

Comment: @egreg, it seems to be ok - you just get `\newlabel{eg}{{\makebox  [.6em][c]{1}}{1}}` in the `.aux` file which just sets the referenced numbers in a box.  But your way looks more robust.