# How to make numbered pages

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

Below is my MWE.

When I use this on Overleaf however, everything come out nicely apart from having numbered pages. None of the pages are numbered, apart from the very first. How can I make all the pages be numbered at the bottom centre of each page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\normalfont\scshape{Abstract}.}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcommand\shorttitle{The Short Title}
\newcommand\authors{Author A, Author B and AuthorC}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\ifodd\value{page}
  \small\scshape\authors
\else
  \small\scshape\shorttitle
\fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\title{My Paper}
\author{The Author}
\maketitle
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{\titlecap}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have explicitly emptied the default page head and foot with `\fancyhf{}` and not added `\thepage ` to either the head or the foot. `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` would restore the default

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I got the `\fancyhf{}` etc from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74034/page-header-alternatively-author-name-and-short-title but I'm not sure what he';s done, only that it worked. Would you mind quickly copying my MWO and editing it so it will work, in an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where would I add `\thepage` ?

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: @yo' that's fine.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to solve the issue :( Do you think you could help me please?

Comment: David's comment has given you the solution. Just add `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` just before `pagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: @Denis Thanks so much!!! I'd been putting it in the wrong place and it hadn;t been working properly! :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much for your help!! Would you like to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?